# missing entries in array of string values

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I'm trying to create a const char array of strings used to identify some hardware channels.   I then want to retrieve these entries by index to label outputs on a user console.    Some of these channels are unassigned and labeled as such with a string "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX", so this value is repeated in the array.

When I try to sequentially display these values in my test code, I see that XX_UNASSIGNED_XX only appears once, and is subsequently skipped. I opened a memory trace in the embedded hardware, and sure enough, the memory only lists XX_UNASSIGNED_XX once, I'm assuming as a sort of optimization.

Is there a way to force the compiler to instead list out every entry in memory as is, duplicates and all?  Or, is it possible that I don't need to do this, and the way I'm attempting to display the strings is incorrect or inefficient and could be improved?

I've played around with how I display the strings, and because it's ultimately a pointer array with each string a different length, I ultimately resulted in recording the length of each string, tracing the array with a pointer variable, then using snprintf to copy the string over to a temp string which I then display.   Any attempt to print the values in the array directly kept resulting in anomalous behavior I couldn't seem to correct.

**FYI** The Display_printf command is simply a printf to the UART terminal with syntax as follows:

```
Display_printf(UART_handle,col_index, row_index, display_text))
```

```
    #define ADC_COUNT (20)

    const char* adcNamesArray[ADC_COUNT] = {
        "KP_CUR_MON",
        "A_CUR_MON",
        "A_VOLT_MON",
        "NEG_15_VOLT_MON",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "FOCUS_CUR_MON",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "K_CUR_MON",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "FOCUS_VOLT_MON",
        "FARADAY_MON",
        "MFC_MON",
        "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
        "POS_12_VOLT_MON",
        "POS_24_VOLT_MON",
        "POS_15_VOLT_MON",
        "POS_5_VOLT_MON"
    };

    char str[20];
    char* ptr = &adcNamesArray[0];
    char* printPtr;
    int nameLength;

    for(int adc_index = 0; adc_index < ADC_COUNT; adc_index++) {
        nameLength = 0;

        while(*ptr == '\0') {
            ptr += sizeof(char);
        }
        printPtr = ptr;

        while(*ptr != '\0') {
            ptr += sizeof(char);
            nameLength++;
        }
        nameLength++;

        char* str;
        str = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)*nameLength+1));
        snprintf(str, nameLength, "%s", printPtr);

        Display_printf(display,0,0,"ADC %d: %s", adc_index, str);
    }
```

So, I expect all the XX_UNASSIGNED_XX entries to show up in order, but instead what I get is this:

```
ADC 0: KP_CUR_MON  
ADC 1: A_CUR_MON  
ADC 2: A_VOLT_MON  
ADC 3: NEG_15_VOLT_MON   
ADC 4: XX_UNASSIGNED_XX   
ADC 5: FOCUS_CUR_MON   
ADC 6: K_CUR_MON   
ADC 7: FOCUS_VOLT_MON   
ADC 8: FARADAY_MON   
ADC 9: MFC_MON   
ADC 10: POS_12_VOLT_MON   
ADC 11: POS_24_VOLT_MON   
ADC 12: POS_15_VOLT_MON   
ADC 13: POS_5_VOLT_MON   
ADC 14: ▒   
ADC 15: @   
ADC 16: ▒▒▒▒   
ADC 17: @▒   
ADC 18:   
ADC 19:
```

A look at the memory dump gives this, which explains why XX_UNASSIGNED_XX doesn't show up multiple times.

```
0x0001C0D8  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0  K  P  _  C  U  R  _  M  
0x0001C0E8  O  N  .  .  A  _  C  U  R  _  M  O  N  .  .  .  
0x0001C0F8  A  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  .  N  E  G  _  
0x0001C108  1  5  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  X  X  _  U  
0x0001C118  N  A  S  S  I  G  N  E  D  _  X  X  .  .  .  .  
0x0001C128  F  O  C  U  S  _  C  U  R  _  M  O  N  .  .  .  
0x0001C138  K  _  C  U  R  _  M  O  N  .  .  .  F  O  C  U  
0x0001C148  S  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  .  F  A  R  A  
0x0001C158  D  A  Y  _  M  O  N  .  M  F  C  _  M  O  N  .  
0x0001C168  P  O  S  _  1  2  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  
0x0001C178  P  O  S  _  2  4  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  
0x0001C188  P  O  S  _  1  5  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  
0x0001C198  P  O  S  _  5  _  V  O  L  T  _  M  O  N  .  .  
0x0001C1A8  uartMSP432E4HWAttrs  
0x0001C1A8  .  .  .  @  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  
0x0001C1B8  @  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since the strings are `const` the compiler is re-using the same string in the array. Why not just access the array using indexes? `Display_printf(display,0,0,"ADC %d: %s", adc_index, adcNamesArray[adc_index]);`

Comment: I tried accesing it using indexes, but it returned garbage

ADC 0:
ADC 1: k▒
ADC 2:
ADC 3:
ADC 4: ▒
ADC 5:
ADC 6:
ADC 7: ▒
ADC 8:
ADC 9:
ADC 10: (null)
ADC 11: (null)
ADC 12: ▒
ADC 13:
ADC 14:
ADC 15: ▒
ADC 16:
ADC 17:
ADC 18: ▒
ADC 19:

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is `MSP432E4_ADC_COUNT`? What is `ADC_COUNT`? Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Sorry, typo.   I fixed it and added the define to the code.

Comment: Using indexes should work. Maybe you can create a [mcve] using indexes that does not work. https://ideone.com/H5fmGF

Comment: I get a warning here: `char* ptr = &adcNamesArray[0];`:  _warning C4047: 'initializing': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char **'_. This is actually rather an error than a warning. You probably want this: `char* ptr = adcNamesArray[0];`. But there are more problems though.

Comment: @Byers1979 As for me then I do not unserstand what this code snippet is doing. For example what does this loop         while(*ptr == '\0') {
            ptr += sizeof(char);
        } mean?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  for some reason the definition of the array ended up padding some strings with extra null terminating characters (everywhere there's a " . " in the memory dump above).   The loop allows me to pass through those and get to the beginning of the next string

Comment: You are making assumptions about how the compiler is laying out the strings in memory. You have an array of pointers, not chars. Those pointers can point anywhere. You can't rely on the strings to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: @Byers1979 You have an array of pointers not an array of strings. Duplicated string literals can be stored as one string literal. So your considerations as I think do not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that the texts are contiguous in memory separated by one or more NUL characters. This assumption is wrong.

This declares an array of pointers to your texts:

```
const char* adcNamesArray[ADC_COUNT] = {
...
```

Just use that array and all of a sudden your code becomes much simpler and correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ADC_COUNT (20)

int main(void)
{
  const char* adcNamesArray[ADC_COUNT] = {
         "KP_CUR_MON",
         "A_CUR_MON",
         "A_VOLT_MON",
         "NEG_15_VOLT_MON",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "FOCUS_CUR_MON",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "K_CUR_MON",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "FOCUS_VOLT_MON",
         "FARADAY_MON",
         "MFC_MON",
         "XX_UNASSIGNED_XX",
         "POS_12_VOLT_MON",
         "POS_24_VOLT_MON",
         "POS_15_VOLT_MON",
         "POS_5_VOLT_MON"
  };

  for (int adc_index = 0; adc_index < ADC_COUNT; adc_index++)
  {
    char *str = malloc(strlen(adcNamesArray[adc_index]) + 1);
    strcpy(str, adcNamesArray[adc_index]);
    printf("ADC %d: %s\n", adc_index, str);
  }
}
```

If you don't have `strcpy` or `strlen` on your platform for whatever reason, you can implement them yourself, they are one-liners.

Some explanations:

- `sizeof char` is 1 by definition, so you can drop it
- the `(char*)` cast is not necessary with `malloc`, it's not wrong to put one, but there is zero benefit in doing so.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is that I can't rely on contiguous memory allocation for the array, or account for optimizations that the compiler might use.   I figured this to be the case, but was hopeful someone may have a work around.   

I initially started out doing what you suggest here, but for some reason the hardware platform I'm using tosses up some interrupt flags when I try to display the text in this fashion.   I guess that's something I'll have to investigate further, as the other method, relying on the pointer to trace the array, is not viable.   

Thanks for the help

Comment: @Byers1979 Did you really do the exact same thing before? I suppose there was another bug in your previous solution and therefore your platform tossed up something.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the interrupt flags, it was unrelated to this problem and more specific to the platform.    But the new issue is that adcNamesArray[adc_index] now only points to one byte at a time.    So, for instance, adcNamesArray[0] returns "KP_CUR_MON", and then adcNamesArray[1] returns "P_CUR_MON", etc....    Not sure why.

Comment: @Byers1979 yes, `adcNamesArray[0]` points to the first byte of `"KP_CUR_MON"`,  `adcNamesArray[1]` points to the first byte of `"A_CUR_MON"` etc. and this is normal, that's how pointers work. I think you haven't completely grasped the concept of pointer.

Comment: I understand that is how it is supposed to work.  I'm saying that it doesn't do that.   Instead of adcNamesArray[1] pointing to the first byte of "A_CUR_MON" it instead is pointing to the second byte of "KP_CUR_MON" and adcNamesArray[2] is pointing to the third byte of "KP_CUR_MON" when it should point to "A_VOLT_MON".   I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: But the code in my answer prooves otherwise... What makes you claim that? Maybe you should ask another question about that specific issue.